# How to fix my accuracy function in `tensorflow`?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have error when evaluating `correct_prediction`.

This is my whole code:

```
def compute_accuracy(testimgName , testimgLabel ):
    global prediction
    v_xs = np.empty([1,224,224], dtype=np.int)
    v_ys = np.empty([1,8], dtype=np.float32)
    g = testimgName[1] 
    v_xs = np.array(Image.open(path+g))
    v_xs = np.reshape(v_xs,[1,224,224])
    v_ys = testimgLabel[1] ## It is a list = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
    v_ys = np.reshape(v_ys , [1,8])##print(v_ys) = [['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '1' '0']]
    y_pre = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, keep_prob: 1})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pre,1), tf.argmax(v_ys,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, ys: v_ys, keep_prob: 1})
    return result
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape , stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    #stride [1,x_movment,y_movment,1]
    #Must have strides[0] = strides[3] = 1
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME') #stride [batch,height,width,channels]

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    #stride[1,x_movment,y_movment ,1]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# size of image
image_height = 224
image_width = 224
number_of_class = 8
# define placeholder for inputs to network
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224]) # 224*224
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 8])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_image = tf.reshape(xs,[-1,224,224,1])

## conv1 layer ##
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,W_conv1)+ b_conv1) #output size 224*224*32 
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1) # 112*112*32

## conv2 layer ##
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5,32,64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1,W_conv2)+ b_conv2) #output size 112*112*64 
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2) # output size of pooling 56*56*64

## conv3 layer ##
W_conv3 = weight_variable([5,5,64,64])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2,W_conv3)+ b_conv3) #output size 56*56*64 
h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3) # output size of pooling 28*28*64

## conv4 layer ##
W_conv4 = weight_variable([5,5,64,32])
b_conv4 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool3,W_conv4)+ b_conv4) #output size 28*28*32
h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4) # output size of pooling 14*14*32

## func1 layer ##
W_fc1 = weight_variable([14*14*32,256])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([256])

#[n_sample, 14,14,32] ->> [n_sample,14*14*32]
h_pool4_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4,[-1,14*14*32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool4_flat,W_fc1) + b_fc1)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1,keep_prob)

## func2 layer ##
W_fc2 = weight_variable([256,8])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([8])
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,W_fc2) + b_fc2)


# the error between prediction and real data
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys * tf.log(prediction),
                                          reduction_indices=[1]))   # loss
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
trainimgNames , trainimgLabels = ut.getlabel(path,textFileName_train)
imgTestNames , imgTestLabels = ut.getlabel(path,textFileName_test)
batch_size = 1
number_of_batches = len(trainimgNames)/batch_size
for i in range(int(number_of_batches)):
    batch_x = trainimgNames[i*batch_size:i*batch_size+batch_size]
    batch_y = trainimgLabels[i*batch_size:i*batch_size+batch_size]
    batch_image_data = np.empty([batch_size,image_height,image_width], dtype=np.int)
    for j in range(len(batch_x)):
        f = batch_x[j]
        batch_image_data[j] = np.array(Image.open(path+f))
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs: batch_image_data, ys:batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
    print(compute_accuracy(imgTestName , imgTestLabel))
```

And `getlabel()` is:

```
def getlabel(path,txtFileName):
    names = []
    labels = []
    dirs = os.listdir( path )

    with open(txtFileName, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        tokens = line.split(' ')
        names.append(tokens[0])
        labels.append(int(tokens[1]))
    i = 0
    listLabel= []
    f = []
    for item in labels:
        a = ('{0:08b}'.format(labels[i]))
        listLabel.append(list(a))
        i+=1
    return names,listLabel
```

When i call print(computer_accuracy) the error appears.

**The error is**

```
TypeError: DataType string for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int64, int32, uint8, uint16, int16, int8, complex64, complex128, qint8, quint8, qint32, float16
```

I do not know why `y_pre` is like that and prediction go wrong. can anyone help me to fix it ?

Comment: Your code is not complete. prediction is not defined in your snippet. Please provide a complete and reproduceable example.

Comment: Yes you right , i should write it. @Sorin

Comment: The answer below is on the right track; you should separate the code that defines the Tensorflow graph from the code that runs it. As to your specific problem, it seems that one or more of the numpy arrays or Tensors in compute_accuracy is of type string. If I'm reading your code right, the label values are strings. You should convert them to numbers. Take a look at the mnist_softmax.py example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py . Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow's philosophy is different than pure Python. First, you **define** *tensors*, then you **run** it.

The first part, where you **define** `prediction`, nothing is running. Its declarative. You declare that `prediction` depends on different variables/operation.

The calculation only occurs when you call `sess.run`. Thus, `y_pres` is not a tensor, it is a python variable (numpy probably) holding the results. Therefore, you are not supposed to pass it to `TF` functions.

**So what?** So you should separate Tensorflow declarative part from the running part. Which means, only keep your second `sess.run` call, everything between this one and the first `sess.run` belongs to declarative part. It should look a bit like:

**Disclaimer: the code below won't even work, cf Problem #1 and maybe other issues**

**declarative part (defining tensors i.e. TF's Compute Graph):**

```
  v_ys = tf.Placeholder( <type> )  

  W_fc1 = weight_variable([14*14*32,256])
  b_fc1 = bias_variable([256])
  h_pool4_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4,[-1,14*14*32])
  h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool4_flat,W_fc1) + b_fc1)
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1,keep_prob)
  W_fc2 = weight_variable([256,8])
  b_fc2 = bias_variable([8])
  prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,W_fc2) + b_fc2)

  # Defining correct prediction as a Tensor as well
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(v_ys,1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

**Running the Model:**

```
def compute_accuracy(imageTestName , imageTestLabel ):
      global prediction
      v_xs = np.empty([1,224,224], dtype=np.int)
      g = imageTestName[0]
      v_xs = np.array(Image.open(path+g))
      v_xs = np.reshape(v_xs,[1,224,224])
      v_ys = imageTestLabel[0] ## It is a list = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
      v_ys = np.reshape(v_ys , [1,8]) ## After reshape it is = [['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '1' '0']]

      # Directly evaluate `accuracy`
      result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, ys: v_ys, keep_prob: 1})
      return result
```

Comment: I have just edited my code. it is total code. can you look at again? @pltrdy

Comment: You should then apply the change I suggest i.e. removing 1 `sess.run`. The fact that you are calling TF function on numpy objects (returned by sess.run) must cause troubles.

Comment: @amirMaleki how are things going?

Comment: As you say @pltrdy  i changed the code , it work incorrectly , i am trying to fix the semantic error that occurred . I appreciate you